# how to split a long string in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a large string with more than 1000 of characters.
I want to split the string with the length of each 100th character or by the length of the screen of mobile device and display the result page by page, want to scroll horizontally as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just `wrap` with `container` and set `width`, It'll automaticlly wrap according to screen size.

```
Container(
     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
     child: Text('Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the'),
);
```

or use `Flexible`

```
Container(
       child: Row(
         children: <Widget>[
            Flexible(
               child: new Text("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the"))
           ],
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: You can also achieve the same result using `Flexible` or `Media Query`.
As a matter of fact, I prefer to do it this way that's why I am answering this. 
First, you need to add `auto_size_text` widget in your project by adding the following lines in pubspec.yaml file.

```
 dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0
```

Import the package in your script:

```
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
```

You can give the maximum lines to expand and the font size by default for more accurate behavior of auto-resizing. Additionally, you can add maximum and minimum font size as well

```
 AutoSizeText(
  'A really long String',
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
  minFontSize: 18,
  maxLines: 4,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, //overflow ellipsis hides the excess character with "..." symbols
)
```

A small set of Example:

```
Column(
       children:[
                AutoSizeText(
                   "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing" + 
                   "And typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been " +  
                   "The industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s",
                   maxLines:4,
                   overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                   style: TextStyle(fontSize:30),
                ),
           ]
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use REGEX
/.{0,100}/

Just like this image example

[image]